# invalid operands of types ‘float’ and ‘float’ to binary ‘operator%’

Tags: c++, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

не могу понять в чём ошибка.

```
 float a_t_pitch = 30.0;
 ...
 if((a_t_pitch % float(30)) == 0.0)
```

При сборке пишет :

/compass_widget.cpp:76: ошибка: invalid operands of types ‘float’ and ‘float’ to binary ‘operator%’
if((a_t_pitch % float(30)) == 0.0)
~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~

до этого все было на int  ( int a_t_pitch )

```
 if((a_t_pitch % 30) == 0)
```

и всё работало, не могу понять что я делаю не так ;_;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Взятие остатка `%` применимо только для целочисленных операндов.

Аналог этой операции для чисел с плавающей точкой выполняется с помощью функции `fmod`, описание которой (которых) можно найти [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod).

Comment: пример кода     `// #include <math.h> #include <QDebug>
    float a_t_pitch = 30.0;
     if((fmod(a_t_pitch, float(30))) == 0.0)
     {
        qDebug() << "qwerrt";
     }`

Comment: При работе с плавающей точкой точное сравнение (`==`) работает, скажем так, не всегда. Потому что точное представление числа с плавающей точкой не всегда возможно.

Comment: а как  тогда надо писать ,  просто я написал  float(0.0)  не знаю чем заменить